# Left join with OR clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I need to get the user count. When I add an `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause it's taking more time to execute the query. How do I optimize this SQL query to minimize the execution time?

```
SELECT SM.ModelId,
   SM.NameID,
   U.UserCount INTO #SM
FROM Mapper AS SM (NOLOCK) CROSS APPLY (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT U.UserNumber) AS UserCount
FROM Team T (NOLOCK)
JOIN Equ E (NOLOCK) ON T.Equid = E.Equid
JOIN EquReq ER (NOLOCK) ON E.EquReqid = ER.EquReqid
LEFT JOIN Information I (NOLOCK) ON T.Equid = I.Equid
JOIN USER U (NOLOCK) ON ER.Key = U.Key
WHERE (T.NameID = SM.NameID
   OR I.NameID = SM.NameID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the below -

```
SELECT SM.ModelId, SM.NameID, U.UserCount
  INTO #SM    
  FROM Mapper AS SM (NOLOCK)
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT U.UserNumber) AS UserCount 
                FROM Team T (NOLOCK)
                JOIN Equ E (NOLOCK) 
                  ON T.Equid = E.Equid
                JOIN EquReq ER (NOLOCK) 
                  ON E.EquReqid = ER.EquReqid
                LEFT JOIN Information I (NOLOCK) 
                  ON T.Equid = I.Equid
                JOIN User U (NOLOCK) 
                  ON ER.Key = U.Key
                WHERE T.NameID = SM.NameID
                UNION
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT U.UserNumber) AS UserCount 
                FROM Team T (NOLOCK)
                JOIN Equ E (NOLOCK) 
                  ON T.Equid = E.Equid
                JOIN EquReq ER (NOLOCK) 
                  ON E.EquReqid = ER.EquReqid
                LEFT JOIN Information I (NOLOCK) 
                  ON T.Equid = I.Equid
                JOIN User U (NOLOCK) 
                  ON ER.Key = U.Key
                WHERE I.NameID = SM.NameID)
```

If that does not help, make sure that you have sufficient covering indexes on both T.NameID & I.NameID to cater for the query.

If you are still having an issue, please let me know what indexes you have on the below tables -

Team T
Information I